# How do I get this array multiplication table to work

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

**Multiplication table assignment**

I am trying to assign a user input array size and add the number 1-the size the array and then print out the array of columns and rows but I don't think I have done this quite right:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class  MultTable
{
    public static int[]rows;
    public static int[]cols;

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        intro();
        getRows();
        getCols();
        fillRows();
        fillCols();
        printTable();
    }

    public static void intro()
    {
        System.out.print("Welcome to the Multiplication Table program!");
    }

    public static void getRows()
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter number of row:");
        int sizerow=input.nextInt();
        int rows[]=new int[sizerow];
    }

    public static void getCols()
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of columns:");
        int sizecol=input.nextInt();
        int cols[]=new int[sizecol];
    }

    public static void fillRows()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=rows.length;i++)
        {
            int rows[]=new int[i];
        }
    }

    public static void fillCols()
    {
        for(int j=0;j<cols.length;j++)
        {
            int cols[]=new int[j];
        }
    }

    public static void printTable()
    {
        System.out.print("\n\nHere is your %dx%d multiplication table:");
        System.out.print(cols);
        System.out.print("--------");
        for(int i=1; i<=rows.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=cols.length;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(rows[i]*cols[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps saying:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at MultTable.fillRows(MultTable.java:41) at MultTable.main(MultTable.java:13)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this code. First, the exception are you getting is because `rows` is null when you attempt to access the `length` in `fillRows()`.

```
for(int i=1;i<=rows.length;i++)
               ^^^^
```

This is because when use `int rows[]=new int[sizerow];` in `getRows()`, it is initializing a new local variable, only visible to the `getRows()` function. You probably want to do `rows = new int[sizerow];` instead. This will initialize the member variable declared above. Likewise for cols.

A similar incorrect assignment is being done in the loops in `fillRows()` and `fillCols()`. For those, you probably want to do something like `rows[i] = i + 1;` instead.

Also, double-check the bounds on all your loops. Some of them start at 1, some 0. Some of them  use `<= length`, some `< length`. You probably want to start at 0 and use `< length` on all of them.